# What is the meaning of (0, )?

Tags: python, multithreading, indexing, args

I saw a line of code like this:

```
thread = Thread(target = startReceiving, args = (0, ))
```

And I am interested to know what is the meaning of `(0, )`? Is that mean from zero to infinity?

Comment: A quick way to find out is `print(repr( (0, ) ))`

Comment: I don't think the `repr` is useful unless you know what you're looking at. That said, you can check out the `type` of it, which would probably elucidate something. `>>> type((0,)) # <class 'tuple'>`

Comment: Is this some sort of light year joke? Or just a tuple?